# Three.js - Scale model

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basicially I like to increase the size of my meshs x-axis by "1" if a radio button is checked. If the radio button uncheck I like to reverse it.

Normally I would do it by simply set the size of the x-axis:

**Something like:**

*If radio button is checked*

```
mesh.scale.x = 2;
```

*If radio button is unchecked*

```
mesh.scale.x = 1;
```

The difficulty in my case is that the current scale level of my mesh varies by some other factors. So it may happen that the scale level of the x-axis is not "1", but for example "3.7".

Since the above function does not work I'm looking for something mathematically that simply add and subtract "1" to the mesh.

```
$('input').change(function () {
    if ($('#radio1').is(":checked")) {
        mesh.scale.x = +1;
    }
    if ($('#radio2').is(":checked")) {
        mesh.scale.x = +2;
    }
});
```

**The problem with my function is that it's adding the value on top of the previously added value. I'm looking for something that subtracts the previous value before adding a new.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the scale factor to the radio button elements like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="2" name="scalers" />
<input type="radio" value="1.4" name="scalers" />
<input type="radio" value="3.7" name="scalers" />
```

Then, the JS:

```
var current_scale = 0;
$("input[name=scalers]").change(function() {
   var new_scale = parseFloat($("input[name=scalers]:checked").val());
   mesh.scale.x -= current_scale;
   mesh.scale.x += new_scale;
   current_scale = new_scale;
});
```

As mentioned in another answer, you may be mistaken in thinking you need to add and subtract scale. So the right JS might be:

```
var current_scale = 1;
$("input[name=scalers]").change(function() {
   var new_scale = parseFloat($("input[name=scalers]:checked").val());
   mesh.scale.x /= current_scale;
   mesh.scale.x *= new_scale;
   current_scale = new_scale;
});
```

Comment: In that case, it's easier: mesh.scale.x += new_scale;

Answer (score 5):

If you think about it, scale is something you multiply with. I want to make my object 10% bigger or twice its size or 30% smaller. It usually is not an additive operation. So I would do:

```
mesh.scale.x *= 1.1; // to make my mesh 10% bigger
```

or

```
mesh.scale.x *= 0.9; // to make my mesh 10% smaller
```